# Powershell Timed Function not returning correct time

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am writing a safety function for my powershell script so they do not run during working hours in case of disruptions. This means that I can automate more as I do not have to worry about the script taking too long as it will pause when needed then resume.

Unfortunately, when it is supposed to be running it is still sleeping. Any pointers on what I am missing would be appreciated.

```
Function WorkingHours {
    $WorkingHours = "20:00-7:00"

    if ($WorkingHours -match '^[0-9]{1,2}:[0-5][0-9]-[0-9]{1,2}:[0-5][0-9]$') {

        $current = Get-Date
        $start = Get-Date ($WorkingHours.split("-")[0])
        $end = Get-Date ($WorkingHours.split("-")[1])

        # correct for hours that span overnight
        if (($end - $start).hours -lt 0) {
            $start = $start.AddDays(-1)
        }

        # if the current time is past the start time
        $startCheck = $current -ge $start

        # if the current time is less than the end time
        $endCheck = $current -le $end

        # if the current time falls outside the window
        if ((-not $startCheck) -or (-not $endCheck)) {


            # sleep until the operational window starts again
            $sleepSeconds = ($start - $current).TotalSeconds

            Write-Host 'Starting to Sleep for'$sleepSeconds

            if ($sleepSeconds -lt 0) {
                # correct for hours that span overnight
                $sleepSeconds = ($start.addDays(1) - $current).TotalSeconds
            }
            # sleep until the wake up interval
            Start-Sleep -Seconds $sleepSeconds
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Not sure if it matters but shouldn't it be `"20:00-07:00"`?

Comment: i think you will have a smoother experience if you define `working hours` as the hours others work. that would give you `7..20` as the range to test ... and that test is very easy & very direct. [*grin*] ///// also, don't sleep the script ... instead, test for "is this in company working hours?" and then add a delay that waits for the needed timespan. i would even skip that and use task scheduler to only run during the needed time allotment.

Comment: Do you know that `$script:WorkingHours` could differ from `$WorkingHours` defined in the function body?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I will see if removing the script from there makes a difference. May be where it was failing. Will update it shortly